# Current logged in ApplicationUser returned as null with UserManager GetUserAsync method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I'm trying to get the current logged in user and cast it to the correct class for manipulation.

In my controller class I have the following code:

```
private async void GetCurrentUser()
{
    _currentCursist = (Cursist) await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
}
```

I call this method in my Index method:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    GetCurrentUser();
    if (_currentCursist == null)
    {
        return View("~/Views/Error/DefaultError.cshtml");
    }
    return View();
}
```

The _currentCursist value will always be null. I tried several different ways but it always results in a null value. Why is this happening?

The `httpContext.User` value is populated with the current user and the `_userManager`contains the logged in user. Somehow it's not giving me the user when using the GetUserAsync method?

Comment: Have you tried to not make the method async? I'm not sure, but i think void methods don't need them to work

Comment: @FrancescoRoggia I tried removing the async, but it will generate an error and tell me to use async. It prefers however to have an async method with a Task return.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I found more information about async methods. It's important to avoid `async void` methods. I changed my method to the following:

```
private async Task GetCurrentUser()
{
   _currentCursist = (Cursist) await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
}
```

and used the following method call:

```
GetCurrentUser().Wait();
```

I'm pretty sure I was getting a null value because I was not waiting for the response. By using an `async task`I'm able to delay the execution, which resulted in the return of the active user.